# How can I show brief instructions in CMake GUI

Tags: cmake

Brief instructions are provided at the bottom of the window when the program is running.But I can't find the brief instructions anymore.Please tell me how to reset CMake GUI so that I can see brief instructions.

Best,
Succubus

Comment: Delete CMakeCache.txt in your build directory. You are using what project? Your question is unspevific and so far unrelated programming.

Comment: @usr1234567  
I am building osgEarth with vs10.

Answer (score 0):

in the menu bar Go to

> view -> perspective -> Code::Blocks Default.

This should bring your status window back up.  Pressing F2 has the same effect.

Regards

Comment: I reset my system,and reinstall Cmake exe.Thanks a lot.